Complex binomial expansion
Using  binomial expansion is it possible to expand, next simplify or reduce to prove that
$$
\left({\cos t\ - { i}\sin t}\,\right)^{\large i} = { e}^{t}~?
$$
I ask this as ${i} = +\sqrt{-1} $ can be used as a complex constant in algebraic / complex operations... so, an imaginary exponent should also in principle be admissible.
How can it be done, and if cannot be done why not so $?$
In the same way can we expand
$$ (1+x)^i $$
into two (real, imaginary) parts $(u,v)$ power series functions by power series term by term expansion? Like in
$$(1+x)^{i}= 1+ i x +\frac{i. i-1}{2!}x^2+\frac{i (i-1)(i-2)}{3!}x^3 ..
= 1+ i x +\frac{-2}{2!}x^2+\frac{i (i-1)(i-2)}{3!}x^3 ..= u(x) + i v(x)? $$
Now I plotted the real and imaginary parts as below, self-answering. Their range is within $\pm 1$ having vertical tangents as expected at $x=-1.$
They appear to me important functions in complex theory.


You can write ${n\choose 2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}$ like its done for fractional coefficients it will give an infinite series that might have some relevance

As we know, $\left[,{\cos\left(t\right) - {\rm i}\sin\left(t\right)},\right]^{\large\rm i}$ has multiple values.  Are you asking whether $e^t$ is one of the values?

Are we assuming $t$ is real?

For a start, we could take $t$ real. Once we see how it goes, we could next consider $t$ complex.

@Gerry Myerson: Sir, for now asking for  a spread out and condensed form culminating in the principal result $e^t$. I suppose other expansions/simplifications  would depend on an $n$ for other branch cuts etc. in the full set.

If $t$ is real, then $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are real, so $|\cos t-i\sin t|=\sqrt{\cos^2t+\sin^2t}=1$, and whatever $1^i$ is, it's not $e^t$.

Someone edited it ( used square brackets that can suggest absolute value =unity). His name not seen now. Just now rolled back for clarity. Sorry about this.  $\left( e^{-i t} \right)^{i}    = e^t$

OK. Square brackets looked like absolute value signs to me, my fault no doubt. Better to use round brackets, that is, parentheses, I think – you haven't rolled back to parentheses. Binomial expansion would give $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}{i\choose r}(-1)^r\cos^{i-r}t\sin^rt$ and all those $\cos^{i-r}t$ terms have nonreal exponents and each of those has multiple values, and I'm not sure what would be a consistent way to choose values for them.

Thanks, parentheses put back.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

@ GEdgar: Thanks again. Are the $u,v$ functions unique single valued, or, are multiple functions still possible?
